# API call on */V1/products/:SKU return wrong values for yes/no fields

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I have a strange Problem

Magento version : 2.1.6
PHP: PHP 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 (cli) ( NTS )

If I send a REST call to mydomain/index.php/rest/de/V1/products/:SKU I get a result which looks fine for the first moment.

The problem is - I have a product attribute "lifetime_warrenty" and the Catalog Input Type for Store Owner is Yes/No.

The problem is - the result on the API REST call ist always: (also for products with YES)

```
{
      "attribute_code": "lifetime_warranty",
      "value": "0"
},
```

And hints? Any workaround you have?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the scope of attribute whether it is store view or global.
2. If that store view, change to `Global`. I changed it to GLOBAL and now it works.